# Redux update state without initializing the state values again

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am creating a todolist application using react and redux. But I am facing issues updating the state. Please find the reducer code below:

```
import { GET_TASKS, GET_TASKS_ERROR } from '../constants';

export function gettasksReducers(state = { tasks: [], getTasksError: {} }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_TASKS:
            return {
                tasks: action.payload
            }
            break;
        case GET_TASKS_ERROR:
            return {
                getTasksError: action.payload
            }
            break;
        case 'UPDATE_TASKS':
            console.log('inside the update tasks case---');
            return [...state.tasks, action.payload]
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Here the GET_TASKS case assigns payload to tasks array inside the state object. But when I try to call UPDATE_TASKS which is in the same reducer, it updates the tasks array to undefined. Please find the action code here:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { UPDATE_TASK } from '../constants';

export function updateTask(txtTask) {
    return {
        'type': UPDATE_TASK,
        'payload': txtTask
    }
}

export function addTask(txtTask) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks', {
            name: txtTask
        })
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({ 'type': 'UPDATE_TASKS', 'payload': response.data });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

I am calling/dispatching the 'UPDATE_TASKS' after adding the task into the db. Do I need to create another reducer to update the tasks in the state ? Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe for the UPDATE_TASKS reducer, try to return " { tasks:[...state.tasks, action.payload] }"?  Also maybe try taking the apostrophes away from type and payload in the addTask action? Do you have Chrome Redux tools? This tool helps when visualizing the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Amr,
It worked after modifying it to:

```
case 'UPDATE_TASKS':
    return {
        tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload]
    }
```

It is updating array of tasks with a task object added into the db.
Thanks